# Power BI: if the date column's value is greater than last year of today's date

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So I have a report I am trying to filer rows based on if the date is within a year of today's date.
Right now the query looks like

```
 #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each Date.IsInYearToDate([Date]))
```

Instead of using the IsInYearToDate function, I would like to return the rows that are within a year of today's date.

I tried using IsInPreviousNYears

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each Date.IsInPreviousNYears([Date],1))
```

However I still need to return dates from this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for dates within an actual year prior of today's date (like, 365-366 days), you would want to do this.

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each [Date] >= Date.AddYears(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()), -1))
```

If you just want within the entire current or prior year you can just make an or condtional on your two queries

```
 #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each Date.IsInYearToDate([Date]) or Date.IsInPreviousNYears([Date],1))
```

Comment: I needed the first one and it worked perfectly.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get today's date using `DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())` and subtract a year using the `Date.AddYears` function. If you want to exclude any possible future dates, you can add that as a condition as well:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each
      [Date] >  Date.AddYears(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()), -1) and
      [Date] <= DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()))
```